# Open a downloaded file in Android N

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

Before `Android N` in my app after downloading a file I open it like:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File myFile = new File(result);
String mime = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
myIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(myFile), mime);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Since `Android N` if I use this code I get an `FileUriExposedException`, as suggested [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#permfilesys) I should use the [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) and get the path like:

```
Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.mydomain.fileprovider", newFile);
```

and then open it with:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor.openFile(Uri uri,String mode)
```

as suggested [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#openFile(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)) where it says `Uri: A content URI associated with a file, as returned by getUriForFile().`

But in the IDE if I do `ParcelfileDescriptor.open...` there is no method `openFile()`
[image]

only `open()` with a File as parameter, and no uri. So how I can open a file in Android N?

**Note:** I don't want to open a file with my application. For example if I download a pdf, I want to open it with the installed app on the phone.

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41570845/6333971)

Answer (score 1):

> Since Android N if I use this code I get an FileUriExposedException, as suggested here I should use the FileProvider

That part is correct. The `Uri` that you get from `getUriForFile()` then goes in your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`. So you wind up with something like:

```
File myFile = new File(result);
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, YOUR_AUTHORITY, myFile);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: I use this code but its shows error can't play video....
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setDataAndType(intentUri, "video/*");
startActivity(intent);

Comment: @bdevloper: Talk to the developers of the video player app.

Comment: @bdevloper: So? If the video player app is crashing, at minimum, there are bugs in the video player app. While there may be ways that you can address the crash, since we do not have your app and we do not have the video player app, it will be difficult for anyone here to help you.